# Azure web app with Laravel connection to SQL server

Tags: php, laravel, azure

I have an Azure free trial account.
This is what I have in the Azure portal (everything in this list is, of course, an Azure resouce):

- **PHP web app** with a working **Laravel framework** installed
- The web app is connected (and update itself) to a **Bitbucket repository**
- A SQL database (and the related SQL server)

Now the question is, **how can I do the connection of the Laravel web app with the SQL database?**

**Other important details:**

1. In the solution, I would like to stick we the free plan (so, please, no solution involving a changing in the Azure plan);
2. I tried to do the connection locally (from a sample code that I got online) but I was not able because of this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()`

I discovered that this error was because I don't have [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) driver installed locally. I didn't even try to install it because my "real use" will be from the Laravel website on Azure.

---

```
<?php
    $serverName = "****.database.windows.net";
    $connectionOptions = array(
        "Database" => "****",
        "Uid" => "admin-****",
        "PWD" => "#####"
    );

    //Establishes the connection
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
    $tsql= "SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName
            FROM [SalesLT].[ProductCategory] pc
            JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p
        ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid";
    $getResults= sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);

    echo ("Reading data from table" . PHP_EOL);
    if ($getResults == FALSE)
        echo (sqlsrv_errors());
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo ($row['CategoryName'] . " " . $row['ProductName'] . PHP_EOL);
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($getResults);
?>
```

Comment: Please share a little of your laravel .env file it might help in understanding better what connections your are making to connect the services.

Comment: @somsgod I didn't put anything in my .env file. The test I runned locally (where I got the error) was with a simple php code I found online (no Laravel). I edited the post and added the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know why you are using this code in laravel.

For Sql Server Connection laravel provides drivers, use that for your case it will be:

In config folder > databse file edit these :

1. `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),` to

   `'default' => 'sqlsrv',`

   if you dont want to use env file vars else update env var 
     to reflect the same.
2. update this driver values:
   `'connections' => [
   'sqlsrv' => [,`

And for more help on deploying laravel app on azure check this:https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-azure-web-app-b55e12514c46

Comment: Thank you very much @somsgod! It worked perfectly. I just added a new 'connection' in database.php named Azure and set it as the default one. PS: the code I posted above was just a test that I run locally to make sure everything was fine with the database I created. PPS: I already knew (and followed) the guide you linked me for creating the Azure web app, a big shoutout to Fikayo Adepoju for creating an amazing guide. Cheers! :)